# what is the value of a++ + a if value of a is 5?

Tags: c, post-increment

i am a beginner in c, and i am finding it difficult to understand the post and pre increment i have given my code below,i already compiled it in a turbo c++ compiler and i got output as
     **a = 6 and b = 10** **but since the post increment operator is used the output should be a = 6 and b = 11 ,why is it not happening?could someone explain it..**

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()    
{
    int a=5,b;
    b = a++ + a;    
    printf("\na = %d and b = %d",a,b);    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: you know what code blocks are, yes? use them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of it.

Comment: Tell your prof/TA to STOP giving out this rubbish homework.

Comment: If this is the work of a professor then it's as depressing as it is concerning.

Comment: If you turn up the warning level in your compiler, does it not emit a diagnostic about the line in question?  I don't know about Turbo C++, but gcc or g++ certainly would do.

Comment: @Bathsheba it's even more depressing to imagine that anyone outside academia would write it:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour of `a++ + a;` is *undefined* in C. This is because the `+` is not a *sequencing point* and you're essentially attempting to increment and read `a` in the same expression.

So you can't guarantee a particular answer.

In order to understand prefix and postfix increments, use statements like `b = a++;` and `b = ++a;`

Comment: what is a sequencing point?

Comment: when i ran it in ubuntu linux compiler i got output as a=6 and b=11

Comment: @prashanth You should Google that: and make your teacher aware of them; constructively of course.

Comment: @prashanth basically a *sequence point* is a semicolon `;`. There are a few more rules you may want to read more about in the [Annex C of the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#C).

Answer (score 3):

What happens in the following?

```
b = a++ + a;
```

1) Is `a` incremented and its original value is then added to the original value of `a`?

2) Is `a` incremented and its original value is then added to the new value of `a`?

3) Is `a` on the right side fetched first and then added to the original value of an incremented `a`?

C allows any of theses approaches (and likely others) as this line of code lacks a *sequence point* which would define evaluation order.  This lack of restriction allows compilers often to make optimized code.  It comes at a cost as the approaches do not generate the same result when accessing `a` in the various ways above.

Therefore it is implementation defined behavior.  Instead:

```
b = a++; 
b = b + a;
```

or

```
b = a; 
b = b + a++;
```

Answer (score 1):

After `int a = 5;` the value of `a` is `5`

```
b = a; // b is 5;
```

After `int a = 5;` the value of `a++` is `5`

```
b = a++; // b is 5
```

but the side effect of `a++` is to increase the value of `a`. That increase can happen anytime between the last and next sequence points (basically the last and next semicolon).

So

```
/* ... */;
b = a++ + a;
#if 0
    /* side-effect */ 5 + 6
    5 /* side-effect */ + 6
    5 + /* side effect mixed with reading the value originating a strange value */ BOOM
    5 + 5 /* side effect */
#endif
```